# How do I check (and change) limits on slurm?

Tags: slurm

Slurm kills my jobs with

`srun: error: Unable to create step for job 2964278: Step limit reached for this job`

after a while. How can I see what the step limit (or any other limit for that matter) is, and can I change it (even if that means being put into a lower qos)?